# function inside a class

Tags: c++, function, class

hi guys i really want you to help me with this problem .........whenever i write that code down below it says "the answer is"  and it doesnt give me the answer .....pleeeeease give me the write code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class steve{
public:

int adding(int a,int b){
int sum=a+b;
return sum;

}

};
int main(){

int a;
int b;
cout<<"enter a number you want to add"<<endl;
cin>>a;
cout<<"enter the other number"<<endl;
cin>>b;

cout<<"the answer is"<<endl;
steve steveObject;
steveObject.adding(a,b);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't outputting the result:

```
steve steveObject;
cout << "the answer is " << steveObject.adding(a,b) << endl;
```